# Why can't Word autosave a file to local storage?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

When attempting to turn on autosave for a document in Microsoft Word, a dialog box opens, saying the following:

[image]

And it then provides options for me to upload the document to my Business or Personal Onedrive folders.

For schoolwork, I primarily use Onedrive, meaning I can use autosave, but I'm just curious as to why Microsoft doesn't allow users to have their documents automatically saved in the same manner when editing a file on your computer's local storage?

Comment: John, that is the default save location. Not AutoSave. AutoSave does not work with local drive storage. The reason is primarily, I suspect, marketing. That is, to get more people using OneDrive and SharePoint cloud storage.

Comment: In my opinion, the autosave online is for collaborating on some Microsoft Office apps with real-time co-authoring to work better. But for files on local server sharing, this new co-authoring feature does not apply to them.

Answer (score 2):

There is no technical reason. Microsoft could easily automatically save - whether continuously or periodically¹ - to the local file system, as just about every other office suite provider offers.

It is however in Microsoft's best interests to keep their users bound to the Office365 ecosystem as tightly as possible. By requiring that autosaved files have to be in OneDrive, they increase the friction coefficient for moving away from O365 to, for example, Google Docs or LibreOffice, since that would involve a lift-and-shift operation of OneDrive files into another cloud provider, made more painful the more files are stored.

*(¹ AutoRecover does this - after a fashion - and has a configurable save frequency. However, in my experience and those of many others, AutoRecover is far from a reliable fallback. I have lost many document edits to a Blue Screen of Death or equivalent, only to find Word or Excel failed to keep an AutoRecover-able copy. I shall rein in my cynicism and not speculate as to why AutoSave is so much more reliable - or, rather, why AutoRecover is so much less so.)*

Answer (score 1):

AutoSave is a feature as you have noticed only available for files saved online as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-autosave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5?ns=winword&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zwd900&helpid=106549&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:%7E:text=disabled-,AutoSave%20is%20enabled%20when,local%20path%20like%20C,-There):

> AutoSave is enabled when working on a file that is saved to OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, or SharePoint Online. If the file is saved to another location (or if it hasn't been saved at all, yet), then AutoSave is disabled. This will happen if your file is on a SharePoint on premises site, a file server, some other cloud storage service, or saved to a local path like C:.

For local storage, AutoRecover can be considered close to accomplishing the same function as AutoSave. From the same [page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-autosave-6d6bd723-ebfd-4e40-b5f6-ae6e8088f7a5?ns=winword&version=90&syslcid=1033&uilcid=1033&appver=zwd900&helpid=106549&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#:%7E:text=if%20you%27re%20not%20a%20subscriber%2C%20don%27t%20worry.%20there%27s%20still%20autorecover.%20autorecover%20helps%20protect%20files%20in%20case%20of%20a%20crash.%20if%20you%20reopen%20the%20file%20after%20a%20crash%2C%20a%20version%20of%20the%20file%20with%20your%20latest%20changes%20appears%20in%20a%20document%20recovery%20pane.):

> If you're not a subscriber, don't worry. There's still AutoRecover. AutoRecover helps protect files in case of a crash. If you reopen the file after a crash, a version of the file with your latest changes appears in a Document Recovery pane.

You will need to enable it, set the recover time as low as possible (1 minute), and set "Keep the last AutoRecovered version if I close without saving".

> why Microsoft doesn't allow users to have their documents automatically saved in the same manner when editing a file on your computer's local storage?

This part is mainly assumption as I have not found the reasons invoked by Microsoft. It could be that they want to promote their online services and that is why they offer a feature that differentiate between local and online saving.

It could simply be that in case of a crash (see above), if an online file is not saved automatically, it could be lost while the local version can be restored (in part) thanks to AutoRecover. (I am not taking into considerations versioning of online files).

Comment: AutoRecover is not the same as AutoSave. See https://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I did not write they are the same. I wrote "can be considered close to accomplishing the same function as AutoSave". Close to does not mean the same.

Comment: Autorecover doesn't do anything, at least not on Mac. The countless times that I've had unsaved work that is gone forever when the computer shuts down, Word force quits, or I lose power...